# Strange Thread Timing on OSX with C

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, pthreads

So I have a very strange bit of behavior with multithreading on C that only happens on my Macbook.  I'm basically doing matrix multiplication and for some reason 2 threads is significantly faster than 1 (duh) but 3 threads is not just slower than 2 but slower than 1!  The value I get for 3 threads holds steady for any additional threads.

On the linux server I have run this on I get steadily faster run times up to 4 threads then it levels off.  Here are the times and some of my code.

Linux:

```
Threads     Seconds
1       6.304504
2       3.334440        No error.
3       2.447981        No error.
4       2.057114        No error.
5       2.121951        No error.
6       2.131267        No error.
7       2.187199        No error.
8       2.304021        No error.
9       2.179180        No error.
10      2.168700        No error.
```

OSX:

```
Threads     Seconds
1       1.228449
2       0.791477        No error.
3       1.799167        No error.
4       1.870556        No error.
5       2.004676        No error.
6       1.934047        No error.
```

Memory Allocation:

```
int ** create_array(int rows, int columns){
    int **a;
    a = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    return a;
}
```

Thread creation:

```
void multiply_array(int**left, int**right, int**output, int threads){
    pthread_t *thread_list;
    thread_list = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        /* get the default attribute */
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        /* create a new thread */
        pthread_create(&thread_list[i], &attr, worker, NULL);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_list[i], NULL);
    }
    free(thread_list);
}
```

EDIT:

More information per comments below:

I'm multiplying Matrix A (1200*1000) by Matrix B (1000*500) to get Matrix C (1200*500).

Running on a 2.7 GHz Intel i7 (8 cores?)

Compile command: gcc Lab4.c -O1 -Wall -o Lab4 -lpthread

I can't post the worker code because this is for a class and I'm concerned that posting my solution online might be problematic.  Essentially, though, each worker takes one cell of the output array and calculates the value that should go in the array.  All the arrays are global variables.  I added a debug statement and it looks like each thread is getting a fairly even distribution of the records:

```
    5       1.856814        No error.
Thread exiting after processing 100001 records.
Thread exiting after processing 99994 records.
Thread exiting after processing 100002 records.
Thread exiting after processing 100009 records.
Thread exiting after processing 99994 records.
Thread exiting after processing 100000 records.
```

Comment: How big are the dimensions on your matrix? How many CPUs do you have? What does your "worker" look like?

Comment: Please post complete code, which compiler you use, compiler flags and your CPU model. Then we may be able to help.

Comment: The most common cause of this kind of thing is contention for some resource across your threads. My first guess would be that the compiler is vectorizing and you're getting contention on the vector processing pipeline, but as others have said, we'd need to look at a full example to diagnose. You can generally do much better by managing the vector pipeline than by spawning many threads. Note that OS X has very optimized matrix multiplication functions in Accelerate (and the BLAS versions are opensource, portable, and available on most Linux distros).

Comment: It's a threading lab for a class so taking advantage of matrix multiplication would defeat the point.  I'll edit with as much information as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was falling victim to [false sharing](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/threadspotter/docs/2011.2/html_doc/manual_html/multithreading_problems.html).  I had chose to use global variables to keep track of where the threads were in the matrix and thus they were iterating through the array randomly.  Splitting up the chunks each thread is to solve makes things go significantly faster, though I still don't get a boost for having more threads.

On Linux Server:

```
Threads     Seconds
1       6.400566
2       3.253767        No error.
3       2.235638        No error.
4       1.982804        No error.
5       1.803468        No error.
6       1.493511        No error.
7       1.445361        No error.
8       1.308549        No error.
9       1.336010        No error.
```

On Macbook Pro (Intel i7):

```
Threads     Seconds
1       1.214193
2       0.584341        No error.
3       0.414696        No error.
4       0.500751        No error.
5       0.493094        No error.
6       0.612082        No error.
7       0.479231        No error.
8       0.539043        No error.
9       0.539322        No error.
```

Comment: Post your code and tell us what processor are using. If you use a MacBook with two cores and hyper threading then it's no wonder you don't get faster beyond two threads. And matrix multiplication is mostly an exercise in careful handling of caches, so multi-threaded matrix multiplication is tricky.